# Replace multiple characters in a string from the command line

Tags: windows, cmd

Its possible replace a staring with another like this

```
set x=abc
echo %x:b=d%
```

The output will be

```
adc
```

But how do you replace multiple characters.
For example I want b=>d but als c=>e

It possible with a loop/for but the question is how to do it on 1 line so I can use it from the command line.

I tried these variants

```
echo %x:b=d,c=e%
echo %x:b=d;c=e%
echo %x:b=d|c=e%
```

I can't get the syntax right or it isn't supported?

Comment: set a search and replace list, then run a `for` loop to replace it for you.

Comment: I removed the [tag:batch-file] tag (amongst others) since you say you want it as a command line...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax supported only one replace per expansion.
The problem is, that mutliple percent expansions in one line or in a command block doesn't work, because the percent expansion will be expanded, before any command is executed.

Therefore this fails, it outputs "abc"

```
set "var=abc"
set "var=%var:a=1%" & set "var=%var:b=2%" & echo %var%
```

But you could use `CALL` to force a second expansion phase.

```
set "var=abc"
call set var=%^var:a=1% & call set var=%^var:b=2% & call echo %^var^%
```

`%^var..` looks odd, but it's necessary on the command line, because on the command line you can't escape percent signs, but you can prevent the expansion in the first round by adding carets in the variable name.

But the solution has a drawback, it appends spaces at the variable.
You can see that by using `call echo ---%^var%---`

To prevent that, you should use the extended SET-syntax with quotes `set "var=content"`

```
call set ^"var=%^var:a=1%^" & call set ^"var=%^var:b=2%^" & call echo %^var^%
```

Now, there are carets in front of the quotes to allow the carets in `%^var` to disappear.

As you can see, the solution is pretty simple

Comment: "As you can see, the solution is pretty simple"  Haha, no!

Answer (score 4):

I realise you said from cmdline, but you also did have the batch-file tag, therefore I will post the batch file solution regarless.

We create a list of `search=replace` as a variable, you can have as many search/replaces as you like, then simply loop through the list and let it run the replace for each and echo final modified variable when done.

```
@echo off
set x=abc
set lst="a=z","b=d","c=e"

for %%i in (%lst%) do call set x=%%x:%%~i%%
echo(%x%
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tried replacing `%` with `!` for the delayed expansion, but I couldn't figure it out. I'm not sure if it's even possible. Can you comment on that part?

Comment: can you please elaborate, @tarekahf?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can use a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) and still have everything in a single line:

```cmd
(for %I in ("b=d" "c=e") do @call set ^"x=%^x:%~I%^") & call echo/%^x%
```

The [`call` command](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) introduces a second parsing phase, which is necessary when you want to write and read a variable within the same block of code.

---

If you have got [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled (like when you started the command prompt by [`cmd /V`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)), you could change the command line to this:

```cmd
(for %I in ("b=d" "c=e") do @set "x=!x:%~I!") & echo/!x!
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a supported Windows system, it will have the PowerShell interpreter.

```
SET "X=abc"
FOR /F %a IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "('%X%' -replace 'b','d') -replace 'c','e'"') DO (SET "Y=%a")
ECHO %Y%
```

If this is placed into a .bat file script, double the percent `%` character on the FOR loop variable. `%a` becomes `%%a`.

```
SET "X=abc"
FOR /F %%a IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "('%X%' -replace 'b','d') -replace 'c','e'"') DO (SET "Y=%%a")
ECHO %Y%
```